# Fillable PDF in Adobe: Javascript code for backspacing across multiple connected fields?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am currently working on a fillable PDF that allows students to type answer to a question across two write-on-lines. I have connected the two fillable fields using the following Javascript code so that when the student reaches the end of the first line, the response continues on the second line. There is a link to a screenshot of the image under the code for further context.

```
var t1=this.getField ("Idea 1a_3");
if (event.fieldFull)
{
getField("Idea 1b_3").setFocus();
}
```

The code works very nice for typing. However, if students need to backspace or rewrite parts of their answers across lines, they can only backspace up to the start of the second line. Is there a code for how to allow for backspacing between line 2 (Idea 1b_3) and line 1 (Idea 1a_3), just like the code allows for text flow to go from line 1 (Idea 1a_3) to line 2 (Idea 2b_3)?

Comment: Don't bother with this. I've been trying to solve for this problem for over a decade. Backspace is just one issue, copy/paste across fields won't work either and you can't select across fields. Adding text within the first field such that it should push text into the second also can't be made to work. I could go on but that should be enough to disuade you.

Comment: Write-on lines are just that: lines to write on by hand. They are useless when you can fill your form on screen. Therefore, if it is for sure that the form will be filled out on screen exclusively, get rid of them, otherwise, add a multiline field where you change the background from transparent to white when it has contents.